# error in a "NO" answer in showConfirmDialog not closing a program when i told it to?

Tags: java

I am currently making a simple program and have come across a error which is probably a mistake. I have a showConfirmDialog command which I want to the "NO" answer to quit the application and the "YES" answer to continue the application. but the problem is that both the "YES" and "NO" answers quit the application here is the snippet of my code that performs this function:

```
    int buttonOutput =myIO.showConfirmDialog(null, "Try Again?", "Try Again?", myIO.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (buttonOutput == myIO.YES_OPTION)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        System.exit(1);
    }
    String inputText1 = myIO.showInputDialog("Please Enter an Object: ");
```

Comment: System.exit(1) will close whole JVM, and it actually is not so good idea to do if you want just to close a dialog window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
int buttonOutput =myIO.showConfirmDialog(null, "Try Again?", "Try Again?", myIO.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (buttonOutput != myIO.YES_OPTION)
    {
        System.exit(1);
    }
    String inputText1 = myIO.showInputDialog("Please Enter an Object: ");
```

I am assuming you are having this code in Main method... so returning on `Yes` terminates your program.